# How to send server-side events from python (fastapi) upon calls to a function that updates the backend state

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, server-sent-events, fastapi

I have the following problem: given a backend running fastapi, that has a streaming endpoint, which is used to update the frontend, I want to send these updates every time the function that updates the backend state gets called (which can be either by an scheduled job or a different endpoint that was hit and caused the state to be updated).

A simplistic version of what I would like to implement would be:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.responses import StreamingResponse

class State:
    def __init__(self):
        self.messages = []

    def update(self, new_messages):
        self.messages = new_messages
        # HERE: notify waiting stream endpoint

app = FastAPI()

state = State()

@app.get('/stream')
def stream():
    def event_stream():
        while True:
            # HERE lies the question: wait for state to be update
            for message in state.messages:
                yield 'data: {}\n\n'.format(json.dumps(message))
    return StreamingResponse(event_stream(), media_type="text/event-stream")
```

And I would like this to keep running forever. Every time the state gets updated, the `event_stream` unblocks and send the messages.

I have looked a threading and asyncio, but I have a feeling that I am missing some simple concept of how to do this in python.

Answer (score 28):

FastAPI is based on Starlette and [Server-Sent Events](https://github.com/sysid/sse-starlette) plugin is available for Starlette

```
import asyncio
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from sse_starlette.sse import EventSourceResponse

MESSAGE_STREAM_DELAY = 1  # second
MESSAGE_STREAM_RETRY_TIMEOUT = 15000  # milisecond
app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/stream')
async def message_stream(request: Request):
    def new_messages(): ...
    async def event_generator():
        while True:
            # If client was closed the connection
            if await request.is_disconnected():
                break

            # Checks for new messages and return them to client if any
            if new_messages():
                yield {
                        "event": "new_message",
                        "id": "message_id",
                        "retry": MESSAGE_STREAM_RETRY_TIMEOUT,
                        "data": "message_content"
                }

            await asyncio.sleep(MESSAGE_STREAM_DELAY)

    return EventSourceResponse(event_generator())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

Comment: Great answer, What does the new_messages() function do here?

Comment: @GooJ Checks whether the data you want to send is ready or not.

Comment: Sorry, I see that's the purpose, I was wondering how it does that? Given new_message() looks like it's a placeholder function

Comment: @GooJ Yes, it's a placeholder. It's totally depending on you to what this function do. For example, in a chat app, it can check the database for new messages and if there was a new message, send that message to the client over the SSE connection. Also, you don't need this function at all if you're going to send the data periodically on every X seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found the example a bit verbose (for teaching) and liked theirs a bit better. See permalink https://github.com/sysid/sse-starlette/blob/e1469cf397716a98d86a62afa488b051f0732970/README.md

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I could find to solve this was to use `threading.Condition`.

Therefore it became:

```
import threading

from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.responses import StreamingResponse

condition = threading.Condition()

class State:
    def __init__(self):
        self.messages = []

    def update(self, new_messages):
        self.messages = new_messages
        with condition:
            condition.notify()

app = FastAPI()

state = State()

@app.get('/stream')
def stream():
    def event_stream():
        while True:
            with condition:
                condition.wait()

            for message in state.messages:
                yield 'data: {}\n\n'.format(json.dumps(message))
    return StreamingResponse(event_stream(), media_type="text/event-stream")
```

Comment: Will this code lose messages if `update` gets called twice before `event_stream` notices the new messages? Take a look at [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) as a more high-level alternative to a condition variable. `update` can put messages into the queue, and `event_stream` pop them off the queue. You get the same behavior you have now, but you don't lose messages and the code is easier to reason about.

Comment: @vini this question is tagged `asyncio` but you implemented a synchronous answer. Look at @saber-hayati answer again.