# it is possible to do push notifications in FastApi?

Tags: python, push-notification, backend, fastapi, web-push

Im developing my backend in FastApi but I want to sent web notifications. I want to know how is possible throughth FastApi.

Im not sure if [pywebpush][1] works or any other library.

Im developing the Frontend in ReactJS

Comment: did you look at this? https://gist.github.com/francbartoli/2532f8bd8249a4cefa32f9c17c886a4b

Comment: maybe you can just try the `pywebpush` library and see if it works?

Comment: You can use MQTT also. Or SSE.

Comment: @Irfanuddin can you share link SSE of python ( question in python). I searched but only found SSE on JS.

Comment: @PaPu https://pypi.org/project/sse-starlette/

Comment: @Irfanuddin thanks you, I will feedback when I try it

Comment: For someone like me `sse-starlette` worked. You guide can check code in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62817008/1406656

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this using [`sse-starlette`](https://pypi.org/project/sse-starlette/).

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from sse_starlette.sse import EventSourceResponse
import uvicorn
import time


app = FastAPI()


async def status_event_generator(request, param: str):
    ctr = 1
    while True:
        if await request.is_disconnected():
            print('client disconnected')
            break
        yield {
                "event": "update",
                "retry": 3000,
                "data": f"{param}-{ctr}"
            }
        time.sleep(1)
        ctr += 1


@app.get('/status/stream')
async def run(
        param: str,
        request: Request
):
    event_generator = status_event_generator(request, param)
    return EventSourceResponse(event_generator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

More details on the payload can be found in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#fields)